# Android. Search/Help: very basic code "frame" for Custom View + Canvas with some bitmaps

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I have been looking through several topics *here*, studied *snake* and *lunar launcher* but I am still at a loss how to get a sound start for my project. *(Project is: porting an existing javascript/xml game to android/Java.)*
All examples I found so far are either *TOO* far going -for me- or just some code lines that you are supposed to integrate and define all by yourself (constructors etc.).

**My problem is:** I have a working "app logic" but ***only "theoretic"*** Java knowledge *(learning!).*

**What I need is:** A few code lines (class?) defining a custom view ("customGame") with say three bitmaps ("tile1.png" .. "tile3.png") placed on a canvas with X/Y values defined.
*THAT'S REALLY ALL!*
**...and:** I'd be ***happy*** if someone also would mention a simple way/method to identify the bitmap touched/clicked.

I feel confident/hopeful to find my way onwards from this first step ...
I am still striving to learn about Java peculiarities; therefore I am *not able* (yet) to fix minor faults in code that most of you might *laugh at!*
***PLEASE:*** only post code that won't depend on my recognizing *obvious* omissions whatsoever.

***THANK YOU VERY MUCH***   to anybody who will spend his time to grant me such a big favor !!!

Clemens (graphic artist from Germany)

Answer (score 0):

As nobody found an answer for my question AND I found one at another forum, I will post my finding here as an "answer" myself - so people will not be misled by a "0 answers" flag in front of this thread.

There is a 2-D-tutorial at anddev.org by Mr.snowflake that met my needs - although I would have preferred one with no separate thread...

[2-D-tutorial (gameTemplate)](http://www.anddev.org/2d_tutorial-t3120.html)

See you,  Clemens